# Does $\sum \frac{a_n}{1+n a_n}$ converge if $a_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ if $n$ is a perfect square and $a_n = \frac{1}{n^2}$ otherwise?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Given the sequence $\left\{ a_n \right\}$, where 
$$a_n = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \ \mbox{ if } n \mbox{ is a perfect square} \\ \frac{1}{n^2} \ \mbox{ otherwise}, \end{cases}$$ 
does the series $$\sum \frac{a_n}{1 + n a_n}$$ converge or diverge?

My effort:

If $n = m^2$, then we have 
$$\frac{a_n}{1+na_n} = \frac{ \frac{1}{m} }{ 1 + m^2 \frac{1}{m} } = \frac{1}{m(m+1)} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n} (1 + \sqrt{n})}, $$ 
and otherwise 
$$ \frac{a_n}{1+na_n} = \frac{ \frac{1}{n^2}}{1+ n \frac{1}{n^2}} = \frac{1}{n^2 + n}. $$ 
Thus we have 
$$ \frac{a_n}{1+na_n} = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n} (1 + \sqrt{n})} \ \mbox{ if } n \mbox{ is a perfect square} \\ \frac{1}{n( 1 + n)} \ \mbox{ otherwise}. \end{cases} $$

What next? How to proceed from here?

An afterthought:

If $n$ is a perfect square, then we note that 
$$\frac{a_n}{1+na_n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}(1+ \sqrt{n})} \geq \frac{1}{2n},$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint.**
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_n}{1+na_n}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{a_{k^2}}{1+k^2 a_{k^2}}+\sum_{n\text{ is not a square}} \frac{a_n}{1+na_n}$$

From what you've done we know
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{a_{k^2}}{1+k^2 a_{k^2}}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac 1{k(k+1)}<\infty$$
and
$$\sum_{n\text{ is not a square}} \frac{a_n}{1+na_n}=\sum_{n\text{ is not a square}}\frac 1{n(n+1)}<\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac 1{n(n+1)}<\infty$$

Comment: then we have $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{a_{k^2}}{1+k^2 a_{k^2}}  = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k(k+1)} \leq \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2} < +\infty.$$ What then?

Comment: yes, got it! Thank you so much. For any $n$, we have $$\sum_{k=1}^n \leq  \sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor} \frac{a_{k^2}}{1+k^2 a_{k^2}} + \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k(k+1)} = \sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor} \frac{1}{k(k+1)} + \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k(k+1)} \leq 2 \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^2}.$$